# How do I monetize my community?

Tags: finance

I started a smaller niche community a year ago and it has been growing ever since, the community is extremely positive and vibrant and I'm extremely happy with how far it has come.

As the community begins to branch out more, I'm noticing higher costs for simply maintaining the community. We recently made a website, created a Discord bot for our Discord server, etc.

How can I monetize my community effectively? Mostly to pay for expenses.

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, let me congratulate you on the incredible growth of your community - it's always heartwarming to see a community flourish and thrive. However, it's totally understandable that maintaining such a community comes with a cost, and you're wise to start exploring some potential monetization strategies.

One well-trodden path is that of advertising - incorporating ads onto your website or in your Discord server could be a potential source of income. However, it's crucial to remember that advertising can sometimes have a negative impact on the user experience, so it's important to strike a balance that works for your members.

Another avenue to explore could be charging for additional premium features or services, offering enhanced (and lucrative!) benefits for paid members or creating an exclusive paid membership tier. By setting up these added perks, you could provide an incentive for people to start using the paid premium features and services to take advantage of everything on offer.

Finally, you could consider monetizing by way of merchandise - t-shirts, stickers, and other fun kitschy items could be a good way to fundraise and provide a tangible way for members to show off their support and fandom.

As with any monetization strategy, it's important to be mindful and considerate of your community members. The last thing you want is for them to feel like their positive experiences are being compromised because of monetization efforts. However, with some creative and off-the-beaten-path approaches, it's definitely possible to find an equitable solution wherein your community can continue to grow and thrive - it just requires some exploration and a bit of that trademark burstiness!

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- Banner ads on the website
- Donations/sponsorships (i.e. let dedicated members sponsor the site for X amount of time and possibly get extra rights/benefits)
- Merchandising - sell apparel and other goods with your branding

Answer (score 1):

You monetise the community to solve their problems. Just reach them to understand their pain points.